# Is it possible to make profit from Online games? How?

Tags: online

Is it realistic to think that I can put time on online casinos, invest my money on poker and be always the winner and have profits?
In case, your answer is yes, please tell me how? Is there any books or tutorials on how to play online poker?

Comment: Simply put, yes. I'm closing this question as it is simply too broad to answer. There are many poker books to explore, many listed on this site. Do a little digging and get involved on a deeper level. Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Thanks Toby for the info, and sorry for the bad question :-).

Comment: No need to be sorry, and you're welcome ;)